# How do you prepare longitudinal data for survival analysis with various specifications?

Tags: r, longitudinal

I have a question regarding longitudinal study analysis and work with R.

I have the following data format:

```
ID Visit Behaviour Distance_to_first_visit_in_month
1    0      1                   0
1    1      1                   6
1    2      1                  12
1    3      1                  50
2    0      3                   0
2    1      3                   8
2    2      3                  16
2    3      3                  25
2    4      3                  40
2    5      3                  60
3    0      1                   0
3    1      1                   6
3    2      1                  12
3    3      3                  24
3    4      3                  30
3    5      3                  55
```

I need the data in the following format:

```
ID Visit Behaviour Distance_to_first_visit_in_month  Status 
1    0      1                   0                         0
2    0      3                   0                         1
3    3      3                   24                        1
```

If a person has 1 every time until the end he should be only censored because the study is finished. If a person has 3 for the first time I need the Distance_to_to_first_visit_in_month because there he has the status 1 in the Kapplan-Meyer curve.

I tried to filter the maximal Distance_to_first_visit_in_month and get the Behaviour. When I bring the data to the wide format it is easy to get those. But I can't get the Distance_to_first_visit_in_month when the person 3 as Behaviour at the beginning or when otherwise.

I have 300IDs with sometimes 11 visits so I can't prepare the data manuell.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks you in advance. 
Best Christina

Comment: And I tried 

```
    fuerKPsort$minBehaviouratthree <- NA
    Dat <- fuerKPsort %>% filter(!is.na(fuerKPsort$Behavior))
    i <- 1
    for(i in 1:nrow(fuerKPsort)){
    j <- 1
    for(j in 1:nrow(Dat)){
    if(fuerKPsort$cid[i] == Dat$cid[j]){
      fuerKPsort$minBehaviouratthree[i] = 
     min(Dat$Distance_to_first_visit_in_month[j] . 
     [which.max(Dat$Behavior[j])])
      }
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't explain how to aggregate your data to the second dataset, I can only show you how to get the ID's that match your conditions and how to implement the status variable. See this example:

```
library(dplyr)

# get id's with only 1
id_list1 <- lapply(df %>% split(.$ID),function(x){
  if(unique(x$ID)==1){
    return(unique(x$ID))
  }
}) %>%
  unlist()

# get id's with 3 as first value
id_list3 <- lapply(df %>% split(.$ID),function(x){
  if(x[x$Visit==0,"Behaviour"]==3){
    return(unique(x$ID))
  }
}) %>%
  unlist()

df %>%
  mutate(Status = ifelse(ID %in% id_list3,1,0)) %>%
  mutate(new_dist = ifelse(!ID %in% id_list3,Distance_to_first_visit_in_month,NA))
```

Please note that you'll get named vectors in `id_list1` and `id_list3`. There are no duplicates, just the name of the element matching the element.

And do you mean Visit number 0 with "at the beginning"? Otherwise you'll have to adjust `x$Visit==0`.

Comment: thank you.Now I get the maximal distance when I have a 1 the with the following code:
` code
fuerKPsort$maxDistance_to_first_visit_in_month <- NA
Dat <- fuerKPsort %>% filter(!is.na(fuerKPsort$Distance_to_first_visit_in_month))
i <- 1
for(i in 1:nrow(fuerKPsort)){
  j <- 1
  for(j in 1:nrow(Dat)){
    if(fuerKPsort$cid[i] == Dat$cid[j]){
      fuerKPsort$maxDistance_to_first_visit_in_month[i] = max(Dat$Distance_to_first_visit_in_month[j])
    }
  }
}
`
and with your code the cases when 3 is the first value.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to get the Distance_to_first_visit_in_month if the 3 is not the first value?

Comment: See my edit, creating the new variable ´new_dist´. If the ID is not in the ´id_list3´ it gives you the distance, otherwise ´NA´.